# Scrapy formatting results

Tags: python, python-2.7, scrapy

I'm just starting to get to grips with Scrapy. So far, I've figured out how to extract the relevant sections of a web page and to crawl through web pages.

However, I'm still unsure as to how one can format the results in a meaningful tabular format.

When the scraped data is an table format, it's straightforward enough. However, sometimes the data isn't. e.g. [this link](https://www.herefordbreeder.net/provinces/england/bedfordshire/)

I can access the `names` using

```
response.xpath('//div[@align="center"]//h3').extract()
```

Then I can access the `details` using

```
response.xpath('//div[@align="center"]//p').extract()
```

Now, I need to format the data like this, so I can save it to a CSV file.

```
Name: J Speirs Farms Ltd
Herd Prefix:  Pepperstock
Membership No.  7580
Dept. Herd Mark:  UK244821
Membership Type:  Youth
Year Joined:  2006
Address:  Pepsal End Farm, Pepperstock, Luton, Beds
Postcode:  LU1 4LH
Region:  East Midlands
Telephone:  01582450962
Email:
Website:
```

Ideally, I'd like to define the `structure` of the data, then use populate according to the scraped data. Because in some cases, certain fields are not available, e.g. `Email:` and `Website:`

I don't need the answer, but would appreciate if someone can point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

All of the data seem to be separated by newlines, so simply use `str.splitlines()`:

```
> names = response.xpath('//div[@align="center"]//a[@name]')
> details = names[0].xpath('following-sibling::p[1]/text()').extract_first().splitlines()
['J Speirs Farms Ltd   ', 'Herd Prefix:  Pepperstock   ', 'Membership No.  7580   ', 'Dept. Herd Mark:  UK244821   ', 'Membership Type:  Youth   ', 'Year Joined:  2006   ', 'Address:  Pepsal End Farm   ', '  Pepperstock   ', '  Luton   ', '  Beds   ', 'Postcode:  LU1 4LH    ', 'Region:  East Midlands   ', 'Telephone:  01582450962   ']
> name = names[0].xpath('@name').extract_first()
'J+Speirs+Farms+Ltd+++'
```

Now you just need to figure out how to parse those bits into clean format:

Some names are split in multiple lines but you can identify and fix the list by checking whether members contain `:` or `.`, if not they belong to preceding member that does:

```
clean_details = [f'Name: {details[0]}']
# first item is name, skip
for d in details[1:]:
    if ':' in d or 'No.' in d:
        clean_details.append(d)
    else:
        clean_details[-1] += d
```

Finally parse the cleaned up details list we have:

```
item = {}
for detail in clean_details:
    values = detail.split(':')
    if len(values) < 2:  # e.g. Membership No.
        values = detail.split('No.')
    if len(values) == 2:  # e.g. telephone: 1337
        label, text = values
        item[label] = text.strip()

>>> pprint(item)
{'Address': 'Pepsal End Farm     Pepperstock     Luton     Beds',
 'Dept. Herd Mark': 'UK244821',
 'Herd Prefix': 'Pepperstock',
 'Membership ': '7580',
 'Membership Type': 'Youth',
 'Name': 'J Speirs Farms Ltd',
 'Postcode': 'LU1 4LH',
 'Region': 'East Midlands',
 'Telephone': '01582450962',
 'Year Joined': '2006'}
```

Comment: What does the `clean_details = [f'Name: {details[0]}']` do? It says syntax error when I run in scrapy shell.

Comment: It's python 3.6+ string formating, equvelent to `'Name: {}'.format(details[0])` of older versions

Answer (score 0):

You can define a class for the items you want to save and import the class to your spider. Then you can directly save the items.